# \$MinNumber vs. \$MinMachineNumber

Tags: numerics

I'm working on some code that is giving me a division by 0 error, but I don't think I'm dividing by any functions that could come out to be 0. At one point it was suggested that this could be caused by an underflow error that wasn't registering as such. (This is all within an `NDSolve` command if it makes a difference.)

In order to hunt this down, I looked up the `$MinNumber` on my computer, and got about 10^-(10^13). However, `$MinMachineNumber` is much larger, about 10^-300. What is the difference between these two values?

Comment: The former is not representable as a machine number; that is, anything smaller than `$MinMachineNumber` is necessarily an arbitrary precision number. Similar assertions hold for `$MaxMachineNumber` and `$MaxNumber`.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks!